# Using JavaScript for basic HTML layout

Tags: javascript, html, layout, semantics, semantic-web

I've been doing HTML layout as well as programming for many years and I'm seeing a growing issue recently.  Folks who primarily do HTML layout are becoming increasingly more comfortable using JavaScript to solve basic page layout problems.  Rather than consider what HTML is capable of doing (to hit their target browsers), they're slapping on bloated JS frameworks that "fix" fairly basic problems.

Let's get this out of the way right here:  I find this practice annoying and often inconsiderate of those with special accessibility needs.

Unfortunately, when you try to tell these folks that what they're doing isn't semantic, ideal, or possibly even a good idea, they always counter with the same old arguments:  "JavaScript has a market saturation of 98%, we don't care about the other 2%." or "Who doesn't have JavaScript enabled these days?" or simply "We don't care about those users."  I find that remarkably short-sighted.

I would like the opinion of the community at large.  What do you think, am I holding too fast to a dying ideal?  Is JavaScript's prevalence a good excuse to use a programmatic language to do basic layout, thus mucking up your behavior and layout?  jQuery and similar "behavior" based frameworks are blurring the lines, especially for those who don't realize the difference.

Most importantly, I would like some "argument ammo" to use against these folks when the "it's the right way to do it" argument is unacceptable.  Can you cite sources outlining your stance, please?

Thanks everybody, please be civil :)

Comment: I don't know if this is the right place to post it, but, javascript should NEVER be used to solve your raw design issues. Ever.

Comment: This would be an excellent forum post - but stackoverflow is not a forum.

Comment: I agree @user1090190, but that's not a good enough reason for many of these people.  Can you tell me WHY you believe that? (I agree with you :)

Comment: Point taken @SamDufel.  I apologize if this belongs somewhere else, someone please direct me there.  StackOverflow gives me some of the best professional opinions I can find condensed this tightly.  I respect this community, and thus wanted it's answers.

Comment: This should be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Slobaum, I voted this question up and voted to close it at the same time... +1 for Bryan Downing's suggestion.

Comment: After seeing some comments, I concede that this should probably be somewhere else.  But I COMPLETELY disagree with "not constructive".  The web is being systematically "crappified" by bad practice such as this, and I think that this type of content stretches beyond just discussion:  new developers need to know this as correct practice.

Comment: @Slobaum Well, I had attempted to migrate it. But, closing is a vote -- most votes wins. You can still move it yourself by deleting this and asking again on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Though, be careful of seeming like you're posting on a soapbox -- giving the impression that you'll just write-off or flame opposing opinions immediately probably won't go over well there either.

Comment: It seems to me that Programmers.SE will not generate the same level of traffic that I would've gotten here.  I understand that StackExchange is trying to accomplish the same type of semantic segments that I'm preaching about, but I do not believe I will get as expansive a cross-segment of answers there that I would have gotten here.  That's disappointing, but understandable.  Thanks @JonathanLonowski, I appreciate your help and opinion.

Comment: I posted this question on Programmers.stackexchange and the reaction was so rabid that I removed it.  I think it's a valid question but they disagree, even going to far as to call this a "rant".  I felt quite unwelcome, and will not go back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consider myself also "old-school" and intend to use javascript in a way that increases user experience, but it is not necessary. So for example (not layout, just easier to understand) i would alert you with js if you haven't filled a required field in the form, but if you have js turned off I'd still "catch" you on the server side.

And yes, wherever I can I try to use static html+css. A good example is: many people use jquery animations, but in some circumstances it is easier / faster / smoother to use css transitions.

Comment: Sadly, many browsers don't support CSS transitions.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you, but because of the 2% but because of the inconsistent page load. As soon as you use client side functions to change the layout you have a short delay between the fully loaded page and the whole functionality. I usually try to do as much as possible with html/css.